# Screen size Samsung S8 android studio

Tags: java, android, fullscreen, screen-size, android-fullscreen

With the introduction of Full Screen device such the S8,
I tough that providing `large` or `xlarge` layouts would do the trick to support the new device but the Samsung S8 is being detected a normal screen size

resolution is:  2220x 1080

Any suggestion on what to do to support the obvious large screen of this device??

Comment: afaik the only special thing about the s8 is its new aspect ratio. the pixel density is not that special. in my experience there are no problems on the s8 when your app works well on other devices with similar screen densities

Comment: This may or may not be a direct answer to your question, but have you already looked into the `max_aspect` [meta](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#MaxAspectRatio) tag? The S8 has a taller aspect ratio than most phones, but since the extra space is used for software nav, it doesn't necessarily impact the resource qualifier chosen. 

A warning about one thing I ran into when using `max_aspect`: I could not actually choose whatever aspect ratio I wanted. If my `max_aspect` was >=2, then I got a 18:9 aspect. Otherwise, it was 16:9 no matter what.